# Magento 2: tracking code

Tags: magento2, ecommerce-tracking

I need to add Tracking code to Magento.

> 1. Put in the < BODY> section on all store pages the code:

[image]

> 2. On Order sucesfull page / Confirmation page to submit the transaction in the < BODY> section put the script:

[image]

Anyone help in which files should I put these codes to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/container.phtml

Don't forget to override it in your custom theme

P.S. It can also be placed in vendor/magento folder instead of app/code/Magento. It depends on how did you install Magento